# Why I can't enter text on form?

Tags: html, css

I use Bootstrap and I want to have on my site player audio
I want the player to follow me on the bottom.

I added this player and added it position: sticky; and bottom: 0px;

Now my forms no longer work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.pingendo.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-4.3.1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://gitcdn.link/repo/likev/html5-audio-player/master/css/AudioPlayer.css">
  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="py-5 bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center col-lg-6">
          <h1 class="mb-3">I sink under</h1>
          <p class="lead mb-4">I am so happy, my dear friend, so absorbed in the exquisite sense of mere tranquil existence.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"><img class="img-fluid d-block" src="https://static.pingendo.com/img-placeholder-1.svg"></div>
        <div class="px-4 order-1 order-md-2 col-lg-6">
          <h2 class="mb-4">A greater artist</h2>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form44" placeholder="Name"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <input type="email" class="form-control" id="form45" placeholder="Email"> </div>
            <div class="form-group"> <textarea class="form-control" id="form46" rows="3" placeholder="Your message"></textarea> </div> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="py-5">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
     <style>
    #player{
        position: sticky;
        bottom: 0px;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: 500px;
        margin-left:auto;
        right:0;
    }
    </style> 

      <!-- Audio player container-->
     <div id='player'></div>


    <!-- Audio player js begin-->
  <script src="https://gitcdn.link/repo/likev/html5-audio-player/master/js/AudioPlayer.js"></script>

    <script>
        // test image for web notifications
        var iconImage = null;

        AP.init({
            container:'#player',//a string containing one CSS selector
            volume   : 0.7,
            autoPlay : false,
            notification: false,
            playList: [
                {'icon': iconImage, 'title': 'Gi', 'file': 'https://github.com/likev/html5-audio-player/raw/master/mp3/try-everything.mp3'},
                {'icon': iconImage, 'title': 'Try Everything', 'file': 'https://github.com/likev/html5-audio-player/raw/master/mp3/try-everything.mp3'},
                {'icon': iconImage, 'title': 'Let It Go', 'file': 'https://github.com/likev/html5-audio-player/raw/master/mp3/try-everything.mp3'}
          ]
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Audio player js end-->  
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

if I add on  #player{z-index: -1;}
the boxes the forms work but then the player stops working.
What could I do?

Comment: Inspect you `#player`. As you can see, It actually spans over way more than it actually seems to, so it blocks clicks from reaching the form. You should limit it to the size (better said: height) you want it to have.

Comment: He have a menu .pl-container which rises up

Comment: I changed 500px from #player in .pl-container and it was resolved. thank you!